# How to make a flashing div?

Tags: jquery, css, glow

I need a `div` to glow from a color to another and vice-versa. This is what I did using [shadow animation jQuery Plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/shadow-animation/):  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lavi/VFtk7/) and it works well... but when I refresh the page it doesn't load and I get this error:

```
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: +1 for your great effort. I'd suggest that you try setinterval for the same

Comment: That looks like a PHP error (server-side). jQuery is client-side. You have a problem somewhere else, I would guess.

Comment: What browser?  OS?  I can't get an error on FireFox 23 (Win XP)

Comment: Is there some server end tech involved?

Comment: Your fiddle does not show any error using Chrome.

Comment: I'm using Chrome, WinXP

Comment: Just so it's said: [You no longer need JavaScript for this.](http://jsfiddle.net/syq8u/2/) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get an error, but just in case it works for you, try replacing

```
function(){
    shadow_normal();
}
```

with

```
function(){
    window.setTimeout(shadow_normal, 1);
}
```

and same with shadow_animar.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a plugin to do this... this snippet will toggle between red and yellow at 1/2 second flux (you can edit the colors and delay as necessary).

```
var toggleColor = function() {
    window.nextColor = window.nextColor == '#f00' ? '#ff0' : '#f00';
    $('#content').animate({'background-color': window.nextColor}, 500, toggleColor);
};
toggleColor();
```